# sha256 result dosen't change

Tags: python, python-2.7, sha256, sha

First time using sha256.

With this code, the result always equals to `4aa6892909e369933b9f1babc10519121e2dfd1042551f6b9bdd4eae51f1f0c2`

what is wrong?

```
def signning(self,D_path):
    BUF_SIZE = 65536 
    hashed = hashlib.sha256()

    with open(D_path, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(BUF_SIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            hashed.update(data)

    hashed_D = hashed.hexdigest()
    print hashed_D
```

Comment: Why should it change? Same input = same output, otherwise your hashing function would be broken.

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead? Is this with *different* files or the same file each time?

Comment: Different file with different result @ Martijn Pieters

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there is nothing wrong with your code, here's a little example showing that hashlib.sha256 is deterministic:

```
import random
import string
import hashlib

random.seed(1)

for i in range(5):
    data = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
                   for _ in range(10))

    hashed = hashlib.sha256()
    hashed.update(data)
    print data, "->", hashed.hexdigest()
```

Run this script over and over and you'll be getting the same output cos the input is always the same ;)

Comment: Thx for anwsering, seems this is a dummy question :D